# Add more columns in NOT IN MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in MySQL called **events** and another one called **vehicles**.

**events** table - `id`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `start_time`, `end_time`, `user`, `vehicle`

**vehicles** table - `id`, `registration`, `model`, `enabled`.

When a person is going to make a reservation, the system has to assign a vehicle automatically (while it is enabled), but for this I have to know that it is not reserved for events in the range of dates and times that the user wants.

I have the following code:

```
SELECT vehicles.registration
FROM vehicles WHERE vehiculos.registration NOT IN (
    SELECT VEHICLE FROM events
    WHERE '$ aux_ini'> = CONCAT (date_ini, '', hour_ini)
    OR '$ aux_fin' <= CONCAT (end_date, '', end_time)
) AND enabled = 'S' 
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Where `$aux_ini` and `$aux_fin` is `start_date` + `start_time` concatenated and `end_date` + `end_time` concatenated.

It worked correctly until the reservations of all vehicles have been made, now you can not reserve any vehicle (although the dates are different) because it ignores the second `WHERE (the NOT IN)` since it only leaves me select a field. Any solution?

Comment: I think the `OR` in the subquery should be an `AND`

Comment: FROM vehicles WHERE vehiculos.registration, looks like you have a typo in vehiculos.registration

Comment: And pleas remember to use pdo bindParameters to insert values into your SQL string otherwise you open yourself to SQL Injection.

Comment: 'it ignores the second WHERE' What second where - is this the whole query?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query